# Flex equivalent of Google Visualization Geomap (choropleth map)?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, google-maps, flex3, visualization

The [Google Visualization Geomap](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/geomap.html#Overview) component is a [choropleth map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choropleth_map) of continents, countries and regions, with colors and values assigned to specific regions. Although it is rendered with Flash, it can only be accessed and customized via JavaScript or GWT API.

Does anyone know an alternative Flash/Flex component that I could easily embed into Flex 3 applications (using AS3) ?

Comment: **Update (06/06):** Three new requirements came up in my projects:
- library/component should be free or inexpensive.
- data involved is confidential so the application should not communicate with external web service/server.
- ability to customize/create any region shapes (countries, provinces, continents) with actions like union, edit path...

I've seen some interesting and promising projects and proprietary components but none really fit my needs. So I opted for my own implementation using SVG Path in Degrafa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had previous success in a non-Flex project using amMap's non Flex maps, but they do offer a [Flex mapping product](http://flex.ammap.com/). I was able to create and define custom map regions and you can essentially treat "anything" as a map, so I was able to create custom regions that weren't otherwise considered a region by anyone else.

I am not sure why this post suddenly showed up as "interesting" as of 1 minute ago given its age, but hopefully this can help someone else :)

Comment: This was the map in question: http://www.bu.edu/cghd/projects/by-location/ - custom regions were "The Americas" and "Europe and Central Asia" but it could very well be a Sprite of a lolcat for all the code cares as long as you set it up right.

Answer (score 0):

checkout  Esris Map solution. I worked with it on a big project and it proved to be a very flexible and functional mapping api

http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/flex/

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. Thanks for the info but my requirements changed (see above)

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few Flex map components you can check out:

Commercial product: http://www.ilog.com/products/ilogelixir/
Open source project: http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/

My experimental component: http://srirangan.net/?p=209 :-)