# I need to design usa interactive Map in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

i need of simple UsA map in flex ,all Area need to be click able as button .

Is there any tool available for designing buttons in various shape in flex or any build in free map is available in flex. 
As vector format so that zoom in will not affect the quality.

i need to design like as shown in this site

http://www.futurevision.com.ua/products/usa_flash_map.php

Answer (score 1):

This is the Degrafa Map Demo. It is still in the samples section so perhaps the site was down at the time.

data viz sample page here:: http://www.degrafa.org/samples/data-visualization.html

Load the "Map Dashboard" sample and Right click/View source to get at the code.

Cheers

Jason.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638175/flex-equivalent-of-google-visualization-geomap-choropleth-map) a while ago but needed more customization.

I used SVG path data in Degrafa to create custom maps of the world, continents, USA.. for a customer. Degrafa used to have a nice US map demo (with source code) as part of its samples, but it disappeared from the web. I don't know of any tool that would help to design clickable Flex shapes. I have no doubt though that Degrafa will provide more support and tools for converting and using SVG.

Some products I found: ilog, ArcGis

And also found this open-source library : GeoVis (birdeye)
But it's very unstable and haven't seen many changes recently.

Answer (score 0):

I'll do that (or, I'll have a designer to do that) in illustrator, and then import the vector format in flex, with the [Embed] metadata.
I don't know if it is a downside for you (for me is a plus), but in this way you have to do everything in code, not with the FlexBuilder UI.